# What is this border bleeding through

Tags: html, css, background, z-index, border

## [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/a5me3/)

I have two divs overlapping with borders on both. When I set the z-index on one higher then the other shouldn't the border also be blocked by the higher z-index div?

Is there anything I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an explicit `background-color`

```
#b {
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background color to something:

```
#b { background-color: #fff }
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mharen/a5me3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

They're currently transparent. Add a background colour.

```
#b {
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:#ffffff <---- here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with table rows in a drag-and-drop sort environment. Set the background to a specific color (style="background-color:White") and it will cover it up. If you don't set a color, it assumes no background and just draws what is behind it (when it's not overlapping, that's nothing, so it looks like a solid background when really it's empty).